# Error on line 24, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A version constraint must be a string

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change the icon of my app, so I modified my pubspec.yaml file to add some dependencies. But after that I'm getting the following error:

> "Error on line 24, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A version constraint must
>   be a string."

This is the code:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
  flutter_icons:
    ios: true
    android: true
    image_path: "assets/icon.png"


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icon.png

firebase_core: 0.3.1+1
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed your dependencies incorrectly, and also missed the `dependencies` keyword from the [pubspec.yaml](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages) file.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: 0.3.1+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You used a double qoute with a dependency version : `flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"` . It should be `flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.3`

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same problem when removing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't place your dependencies under the `dependencies` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you one more way of changing you app icon.
Download your icon and generate a custom icon for different screen size using app icon generator - https://appicon.co/ and select the devices for which your application has to work, this website will generate you custom icons. Download the generated icons extract it in a convenient place in your machine.

1. For Android: 
   click on your project on the left files - navigate to Android folder -> app -> src -> main -> res -> right click on reveal in finder, replace all the mipmap folder with the one generated using appicon.co
2. For iOS: 
   click on ios folder -> Runner -> Assets.xcassets - > AppIcon.appicon.set -> Reveal in finder. now replace all the content in the folder with the one generated using the appicon.co

stop and restart your application, and the icon should be changed